# java StringBuilder DeleteCharAt( int a ) method not working properly

Tags: java

I am trying to use the method but my result vaires. 
this is the text with html code that i want to get rid of.

> A Shropshire Lad>  >  >>>>>> >>>>>>A Shropshire Lad>>>by A.E. HousmanPublished by Dover 1990>>>>>>This collection of sixty three poems appeared in 1896.Many of them make references to Shrewsbury and Shropshire,however, Housman was not a native of the county. The Shropshireof his book is a mindscape in which he blends old ballad meters,classical reminiscences and intense emotional experiences"recollected in tranquility." Although they are notparticularly to my taste, their style, simplicity andtimelessness are obvious even to me. Below are two short poemswhich amused me, I hope you find them interesting too.>>

And this is the output i get.

A Shropshire Lad    >>> >>>A Shropshire Lad>by A.E. HousmanPublished by Dover 1990>>>This collection of sixty three poems appeared in 1896.Many of them make references to Shrewsbury and Shropshire,however, Housman was not a native of the county. The Shropshireof his book is a mindscape in which he blends old ballad meters,classical reminiscences and intense emotional experiences"recollected in tranquility." Although they are notparticularly to my taste, their style, simplicity andtimelessness are obvious even to me. Below are two short poemswhich amused me, I hope you find them interesting too.>

IT refuses to delete some of the arrows. WHy ? : (

My code

```
    int c;
    c = 0;
    System.out.println( s);
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);

    while( c < str.length()-1)
    { 

        if( str.charAt(c) == '>' )
        {
            str = str.deleteCharAt(c);
            c+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            c+=1;
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: `StringBuilder` is ok :)
Reverse order in the loop should help

Comment: It worked ! Why is that ?

Comment: HINT: Consider `>>>`, remove the first one; that leaves `>>`. Your code doesn't go back and consider the first character again. Now you're on the second, remaining, `>`.

Comment: Oh , thanks ! It is pretty obvious.

Comment: actually the order doesn't matter. If you remove a char you shouldn't increment c so just remove `c+=1`in if block. And by the way the condition in while should be `while( c < str.length())`

Answer (score 0):

When you delete a character, then all following move one position to the left. When you then increment your index `c` you are effectively skipping one character.

Lets assume yout index points to the 'd':

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
   ^
```

Then you delete the 'd':

```
abcefghijklmnopqrst
   ^
```

Now the index points already to the next character you want to process. But you increment the index, so you are pointing to the 'f':

```
abcefghijklmnopqrst
    ^
```